# Silex variable mount point?

Tags: php, silex

I have a series of pages that currently look something like this as route definitions:

```
$app->get('/{region}/{instance}/events', 'MyApp\EventsController::index');
$app->post('/{region}/{instance}/events', 'MyApp\EventsController::add');
$app->get('/{region}/{instance}/event/{id}', 'MyApp\EventsController::edit');
$app->post('/{region}/{instance}/event/{id}', 'MyApp\EventsController::update');
```

I then have an `EventsController` class that has to have `region` and `instance` as parameters to all four functions (`index`, `add`, `edit`, and `update`). I'm wondering if it's possible to clean that up, and possibly move the `region` and `instance` values into the global `$app` object.

I'd love to be able to do

```
$app->mount('/{region}/{instance}/', new MyApp\EventsControllerProvider());
```

And have the `EventsControllerProvider` validate the `region` and `instance` variables, and map the "event" routes on top of that path, but it seems that mount points can't contain variables (the `ControllerProviderInterface::connect()` method doesn't allow extra parameters).

Is there a clean way to do this? I thought of this method, which seems counter to the other routing mechanisms:

```
$app->get('/{region}/{instance}/{action}' function($region, $instance, $action) use ($app) {

  if ($app['myapp.valid-region']($region) === false) return $app->abort(404);
  if ($app['myapp.valid-instance']($instance) === false) return $app->abort(404);


  switch ($action) {
    case 'events':
      $c = new MyApp\EventsController();
      return $c->index();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Years later, I found a solution. It may not have existed back then, but it does now. As I mentioned in my original question, the `ControllerProvider` doesn't have additional parameters that can be helpful, but middleware can solve this issue:

```
$app->mount('/{region}/{instance}/', new MyApp\EventsControllerProvider())
->before(function(Request $r, Application $a) {
  $region = $r->attributes->get('region');
  $instance = $r->attributes->get('instance');
  $regionInfo = $a['myRegionService']($region, $instance);
  if ($regionInfo === false) {
    return $a->abort(404, 'No such region');
  }
  $a['currentRegionInfo'] = $regionInfo;
});
```

Now, my Controllers mounted under my `EventsControllerProvider` don't need to do any validation on the region/instance, since that's done beforehand (and a 404 returned if there's a problem). If the controllers need to know the current region, they can pull it out of `$a['currentRegionInfo']`, since that will have been set already. Because this middleware is bound only to this specific route collection, it's not called for other routes defined in the application.

The variables defined in the URL are exposed on the `Request` object under its `attributes` parameter. Technically any of the Controllers could still get the `region` and `instance` parameters passed into their methods, but there's no need for that now.

Answer (score 0):

It's not exactly as your problem but I needed something a bit similar for an API with resources and sub-resources in the form of:

```
/resources/{resource_id}/subresources/{subresource_id}
```

With different sub-resources possible.

I ended doing matching against the resource first, then create a new request for the sub-resource, with resource_id as a query parameter.

I don't think it's ideal and very clean but it works (for now):

```
$app->mount('/subresource/1', new Subresource1ControllerProvider());
// etc for subresource 2/3/n

$app->match('/resources/{resource_id}/{slug}', function (Request $request, $resource_id, $slug) use ($app)
{
    $currentQueryParams = $request->getQueryString();
    $newQueryParams = '?resource_id=' . $resource_id .
        ((empty($currentQueryParams)) ? '' : '&' . $currentQueryParams);

    $subRequest = Request::create('/' . $slug . $newQueryParams, $request->getMethod(), $request->request->all(),
                        $request->cookies->all(), array(), $request->server->all(), $request->getContent());

    if ($request->getSession()) { $subRequest->setSession($request->getSession()); }

    return $app->handle($subRequest, HttpKernelInterface::SUB_REQUEST);
})
->assert('slug', '.*');
```

And then in my controller provider :

```
class Subresource1ControllerProvider implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        $controllers = $app['controllers_factory'];

        $controllers->get('/', function (Request $request) use ($app) {

            $app['resource.id'] = $request->query->get('resource_id');
            $resource = $app['resource'];

            // do your thing ...

            return /* whatever */
        });

        return $controllers;
    }
}
```

The downside is that it makes /subresource/{subresource_id} directly accessible as well.

Comment: Yes, that's a big downside; having the alternate URL available as well. I suppose you could make it more inaccessible by making the secondary route have a random prefix, like `$app->mount('/thisisnotarealurldonotuse/subresource/1', ...`, and then `Request::create('/thisisnotarealurldonotuse' . $slug ...`

Comment: That's not a bad idea.

It's true that in my case I don't really care if the resource is given in the query string or not, as it just have to fail if no resource_id is given.

Answer (score 0):

If you can check for valid *region* and *instance* via a regular expression, you can add *assert* claims in the *connect* method:

```
namespace MyApp;

class EventsControllerProvider  implements ControllerProviderInterface
{
    public function connect(Application $app)
    {
        $controller = $app['controllers_factory'];

        $controller->get('/', [ $this, 'handleRoot' ]);

        $controller->assert('region', 'europe|asia|america');
        $controller->assert('instance', 'some regular expression');

        return $controller;
    }

    public function handleRoot(Request $request)
    {
        $region = $request->attributes->get('region');
        $instance = $request->attributes->get('instance');
        ...
        return ...;
    }
}
```

Then where you have your *mount*s:

```
$app->mount('/{region}/{instance}/', new EventsControllerProvider());
```